# My camera object is invisible in viewport, and tools don't work for it

Tags: objects, 3d-view, camera

My camera boundaries are invisible in viewport, I can't move it with tools (I can move it only using CTRL + ALT + 0). I can't zoom in, rotate or anything. I don't think it has anything to do with collections. I'm using blender 2.81. As you can see, light is 100% visible with no such problems. I launched older version of the project, and I can move the camera normally. I think I might accidentaly changed some settings.

[image: in]

Comment: Is the camera locked to view?

Comment: No, the camera isn't locked to view.

Comment: The Object Type Visibility is greyed (eye icon on the top right), which means you've made some type of objects invisible, are you sure you haven't made the camera invisible?

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. Thanks. I'm just silly :P